# Plot inverse square distance law with distance intervals instead of actual distances

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I have a set of experimental points that I want to plot to confirm inverse square law, i.e., force $= - G M m / r ^2.$ But I have accelerations or force measured for points of which I know the distance to a fixed point, instead of the original distance from the center of Earth. How can I adjust the data in Excel, what have I to represent in x's and y's axis so I can adjust the actual data to the expected law?
Of course, the result will change heavily if the distance of the different points is of 1 km., and we are 6,700 km from Earth, than if the distance to Earth is much lower. But somehow, the unknown distance to the Earth will surface somehow from the experimental data, if we have enough points, right?

Comment: How large is your r compared ti radius of earth. how do you know the mass of earth? Do you exactly know the distance to earth center at the point of your experiment?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about the distance to Earth. I only know the intervals and only have the experimental data. Other data would be known, but even if they are not known, it will be a constant GMm, and from the data, if there are enough points, it can be deducted. I mean, the question could be even if I am collecting data in another planet. With enough points (and not too many), I must be able to confirm inverse square root with interval of distances (which is what I can measure) and measurements. And no, please don't assume mgh aproximation!!!!

Comment: Are you asking about fitting a model with one unknown parameter?

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure about how many unkown parameters I have. I think they are two. If we are in an unkown planet, the first unkown parameter is GM, and the other is R_0. The model is a(r) = - GM/(R_0 + r)^2 and the measured values are a(r) and r. With a bunch of experimental data (a and r), plot and adjust the graph so I can adjust to the theoretical model. It will yield the GM and R_0 as a result, and confirm that the Newton's law is fullfiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points is enough two calculate R and GM
just take $\sqrt{\frac{a_1}{a_2}}=\frac{R-r_2}{R-r_1}$  resolve for R  an then use $a_1$ to solve for GM

Comment: I see your point, but then, how do I fit the data? I mean, if we have 10 points, I could evaluate R and GM for a1 with a2, a2 with a3, etc., and take the mean value? Later, I would use logarithms to adjust to 1/r^2, i. e., to a straigh line with slope -2 ? ( log(a) = log(constant) - 2*log(r) => y = mx + b? I am not very sure how to fit the experimental data.

Comment: plot $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}*GM-R $ for ai and ri